# Change display properties of graphics in lithium theme

Tags: blogdown

First of all thanks to the developers of blogdown. I just started my first blogdown-blog on github / netlify and it looks really nice.

There is one issue that I would like to change:
On mobile devices, graphics from R code chunks are displayed in a way that I can see only the left part of the graphics. Ideally, I would want to reduce the size of the graphics on mobile devices so they fit to the height and the width of the screen.

Is this possible? Where would introduce changes?

Here is the link to my blog: https://sbloggel.netlify.com/

(I have only the most minimal knowledge about web programming).

Thanks in advance for any advice or pointers to relevant resources to start learning and best greetings,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

I just accidentally found a potential solution that is sufficient to me.

Most (maybe all) figures on my blog will be produced by R code chunks.

By specifying the 'out.width'-parameter in the code chunk that produces the figure, the size of the figure will be fitted to the screen size as far as I can see:

````
```{r out.width = "100%"}
plot(1:10)
```
````

Thanks nonetheless!